# Performance issue when Apppool identity is Network Service on IIS 6.0

Tags: iis-6

I have a very sluggish performance issue when a website is runnig under appPool identity configured to "Network Service" on IIS 6.0.

When i change the apppool identity to network account then the perofmrance is great.

Can you please suggest for any resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is curious to me that it would be slow--and this really isn't an answer.  But the excellent and free [Process Monitor tool from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can likely help you sort out what is going on.

Download it, and allocate 20 minutes to play with it--it may be within that time you can get to the root of your problem.  And in the process you'll have a new tool in your toolbox that you can use to amaze and impress your friends.